# ¿Cómo obtener los cuartiles por columna de una base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, r, windows, variables, rstudio

Quiero obtener los cuartiles de una base de datos, pero la base es una especie de serie de tiempo. Quiero obtener los cuartiles de la primera semana de los años (2008 a 2017) y así obtener los cuartiles de cada uno de los años para las diferentes semanas y después proponer cómo variables los cuartiles obtenidos por semana.

Busco realizar un análisis de canales endémicos.

Mi base de datos está adecuada por año y sus 53 semanas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo algo así:

```
set.seed(2019)
panel <- data.frame(año = rep(2008:2017, each=53),
                    semana = rep(1:53, times=10),
                    casos = sample(0:42, 53*100, replace = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con R base, puedes hacer algo así:

```
# Creamos un ejemlo
set.seed(2019)
panel <- data.frame(año = rep(2008:2017, each=53),
                    semana = rep(1:53, times=10),
                    casos = sample(0:42, 53*100, replace = TRUE))

# Agrupamos la base de datos por semana y calculamos los cuartiles
final <- aggregate(casos ~ semana, 
                   data=panel, 
                   FUN=function(x) {
                       c(quantile(x)[2],
                         quantile(x)[3],
                         quantile(x)[4]
                       )
                   })
head(final)

  semana casos.25% casos.50% casos.75%
1      1     13.00     21.00     30.00
2      2     12.00     21.00     33.00
3      3      8.75     17.50     28.00
4      4      9.75     20.50     29.00
5      5     10.75     18.00     29.25
6      6      9.75     20.50     33.25
```

Detalle:

- Con `aggregate(casos ~ semana, data=panel, ....)` agrupamos por semana
- Con `FUN=` definimos un vector de funciones que se aplicarán a cada grupo (semana), cada función es el `quantile()` que buscamos calcular

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta. Tal vez me equivoqué al plantear mi duda, pero quiero obtener los cuartiles con los datos de la primera semana y todos los años. O sea, del 2008 al 2017 sacar sus cuartiles con la primera semana y así consecutivamente de las demás. Sé que de la primera semana los datos son: Q1 = 7, Mediana = 38 y Q3= 79.

Comment: @JonathanFloresLira, ok, entonces lo que necesitas es agrupar por # semana, si es así edité mi respuesta

Comment: Te agradezco mucho, Patricio. Ahora lo que me causa duda es cómo hacer que aparezcan como variables los cuartiles para poder graficarlos.

Comment: @JonathanFloresLira, ¿a que te refieres con variables? los cuartiles así generados ya son variables del dataframe. Si de casualidad de refieres a indicar un nombre, puedes si lo defines en la función, `c(c1 = quantile(x)[2], c2 = quantile(x)[3] ...)`